# Android Room - How to Add a TypeConverter

Tags: android, android-room

I'm currently learning about the Room Persistence and I just want to ask on how to create a TypeConverter for a custom class?

**`Brand.kt`**

```
@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = "brand")
data class Brand (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    val name: String
) : Parcelable
```

**`Product.kt`**

```
@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = "product")
data class Product(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "brand")
    val brand: Brand, // This variable is my problem, I don't know how to fix it...

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    val name: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "price")
    val price: Int
) : Parcelable
```

Right now I'm encountering an error and it says,

> **error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.**

and pointing to my `Product` class

I tried to put an annotation to my `Product` class like `@TypeConverters(Brand.class)` and still the error is popping, I really don't know what to do.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `@Embedded` instead.

```
@Embedded
val brand: Brand,
```

From [docs:-](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Embedded)

> Can be used as an annotation on a field of an Entity or Pojo to signal
>   that nested fields (i.e. fields of the annotated field's class) can be
>   referenced directly in the SQL queries.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, by using of `@Embedded` I'm currently now facing a new error `error: A field can be annotated with only one of the following:ColumnInfo,Embedded,Relation` any idea about this?

Comment: Remove `@ColumnInfo`.